# Proper alternative for System.Classes.MaxListSize

Tags: delphi

Sometimes one uses `System.Classes.MaxListSize`.

```
procedure GList.SetCapacity(NewCapacity: Integer);
begin
  if (NewCapacity < FCount) or (NewCapacity > MaxListSize) then
    Error(string(@SListCapacityError), NewCapacity);
  if NewCapacity <> Capacity then
  begin
    SetLength(FList, NewCapacity);
  end;
end;
```

But it's deprecated.

```
const
  MaxListSize = MaxInt div 16 deprecated;
```

I get this warning:

> Framework\generics\templates\GList_Implementation.inc(215): warning
> W1000: Symbol 'MaxListSize' is deprecated

I suppose it's deprecated for the purpose of 64bit support.

What could be a proper alternative for `System.Classes.MaxListSize` that supports both 32 and 64 bit?

**Update #1 - 2021-10-06**
When I do following:

```
implementation

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  il: TList<integer>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  il := TList<integer>.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to MaxInt do
      il.Add(i);
  finally
    il.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I get an out of memory exception. There is no more check, isn't there?

Comment: For Delphi's own code it appears to do the validation work in `SetLength()` and there is no longer a check in SetCapacity against a MaxListSize. So you could just delete `or (NewCapacity > MaxListSize)` or wrap it in compiler conditionals. Note this is a rather old change.

Comment: I checked it with `TList<T>`. There is no check anymore. I get out of memory exception.

Comment: *I get an out of memory exception. There is no more check, isn't there?* Doesn't the memory exception (instead of a system crash) indicate that there is a check? A fixed limit as before doesn't make sense in 64 bit systems as the limiting factor is the amount of memory.